# Recovering erroneously deleted Iphone code, from Iphone?

Tags: iphone, data-recovery

I was working on my game last night in XCode and wanted to remove a couple of old files from my Development folder.  I Multi-Selected them, and deleted permanently.  Come to find out seconds after, that I also had the main source file for my game also selected, and deleted.

I've tried to recover the file any other way I know how, (not in trash bin, data recovery tools) etc.

The only other thing I could think of to try is to try and somehow get the code from the debug test app I have on my iphone.  I'm pretty sure it's not possible, but figured I'd ask anyway, or if anyone else had a potential solution, because I lost a lot of work -- but I have no one to blame but myself :(

Comment: This is a good learning opportunity to start using the built in git support in Xcode 4.  https://github.com/blog/810-xcode-4-released-with-git-integration

Comment: So sorry to read that - hope you'll manage to recreate your work. And yes, GIT / SVN / ... are your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no.

The source code which is just a series of text files would have been made into assembly code, from there it would be make into machine code for the device and put into an IPA file. You simply cannot retrieve the original source code from this.